# NUMBER_OUTSIDE_VALID_RANGE: value outside of valid range on numeric field: 100.0

Tags: api, error, error-messages, bulk-api

I get this error in the results of a Bulk API upsert:
`'NUMBER_OUTSIDE_VALID_RANGE:Normalized Score: value outside of valid range on numeric field: 100.0:normalized_score__c --'`

The metadata for that custom object uses `'type': 'Number', 'precision': 10, 'scale': 8`.

Is range referring to the value, as in a minimum and maximum value, that 100.0 is not between?

Or does it have to do with `'scale'` or `'precision'` (which seem plenty high to incorporate the number `100.0`)?

More generally, how does one resolve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Precision is the total number of digits allowed both left and right of the decimal, and scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal. The number of digits just to the left of the decimal is `precision`-`scale`, or in other words, 2 significant digits. As configured, the field's maximum value is 99.99999999. You'd want to edit the field to allow 3 significant digits instead (precision would read 11 instead of 10).